# TextView gets overlaped(instead of Overwriting)in a Preference Screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-preferences, preferencescreen

I am trying to build a preference screen which consists of a Layout with some TextViews and EditText Preference.

When I use textView.setText(inputString) in the Activity, it does not overwrite the existing TextView, instead it creates a new copy of TextView with inputString as text and it overlaps with the existing TextView. Is there any way that the setText overwrites the existing TextView itself.

This is the XML Layout with the TextView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blue"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        ></ListView>
    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/pseudoBlack"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="59dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/pseudoBlack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginStart="100dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/pseudoBlack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="43dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView11"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginStart="21dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is the Preference Screen I am using.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    >
    <Preference android:layout="@layout/inner" android:key="innerkey"
        />
    <Preference android:key="mskey"

        android:title="show"
        />
    <EditTextPreference android:key="editpref"
        android:title="Add"
        />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

This is the Activity Class in which I am trying to do setText().

```
package com.example.asus.layoutcheck;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SecondaryActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.inner);
        TextView txt1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView txt2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView5);
        TextView txt3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView11);

        txt1.setText("First Text");
        txt2.setText("Second Text");
        txt3.setText("Third Text");

        final String message = "This is the message" ;
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref);
        final Preference msg = findPreference("mskey");
        msg.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

                msg.setSummary(message);
                return true;
            }
        });
        Preference edit = findPreference("editpref");

    }
}
```

I have added the screenshot of the result.[image]

How can I overcome this Issue?Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

replace `setContentView(R.layout.inner);` with `addPreferencesFromResource(//your preferenceScreen);`

Comment: It did not work. The app stops working if I replace the setContentView.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this similar issue, and it happens with other view as well like a TextureView inside a FrameLayout. I resized my TextureView smaller and I can still see the previous TextureView in the back flickering.

What made it work is funny -> I just put a black background color (probably any color) to my layout (LinearLayout) and it is working fine now.

I added: android:background="#000000"

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible"
    tools:context=".CameraActivity">
```

It seems the background is not cleared, if it doesn't know what color to clear it with.